# change the string into uppercase and lowercase in java

Tags: java

I'm getting the string from the user.In the first word of the string the first letter will be as it is then convert the remaining to upper case and in the second word keep the first two letters as it is and then convert the remaining to upper case.Likewise the pattern continues for every words in the string.For eg if the input is "I Love java Programs" and the output will be "I LoVE javA ProgRAMS"(If the starting letters is in uppercase keep as it is don't change into lower case). I tried little bit i don't know how to continue next?Also I am not clear whether i start it correct?

```
 String s="I Love java Programs";
        String str="";
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray(); 
        str=str+s.charAt(0);
        String str1="";
        for(int i=1;ch[i]!=' ';i++)
        {
            char c=ch[i];
            char cc= Character.toUpperCase(c);
            str=str+cc;
        }
       System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
 String s = "I Love java Programs";
 String[] strArr = s.split(" ");
 for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    String str = strArr[i];
    int min = Math.min(i + 1, str.length());
    String finalStr = str.substring(0, min) + (str.substring(min, str.length())).toUpperCase();
    System.out.print(finalStr + " ");
 }
```

The output will be:- "I LoVE javA ProgRAMS "

strArr[] will store the values like this: [I, Love, java, Programs]

Iterate over the array and use the index to determine how many characters we need to ignore (i.e. for 1st word 1 character, for 2nd word 2 characters and so on), for that I am using `str.subString(0, i+1)` 
And we will use String#toUpperCase() to convert the remaining characters to upper case.

Comment: No chance of receiving [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), right?

Comment: yes, we can get IndexOutOfBound, need to update the code for that as well.
But I am assuming if the problem is like that "In the first word of the string the first letter will be as it then converts the remaining to upper case and in the second word keep the first two letters as it is and then convert the remaining to upper case"
Then this problem will not be there

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining your code. If you just dump the code here, you support a "write code for me" mentality, attracting poor questions to this site and allowing clueless programmers to achieve a degree and later work as probably still clueless programmers.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion, added the explanation also

Comment: it does not work for the input "java is a programming language".....It shows stringindexoutofbound exception

Comment: @Harini, yes you need to put additional checks for handling the length of the string as Abra also suggested.